# Startup VirtualBoxSDK test application returns error "Error creating virtual box instance"

Tags: c++, c, com, virtualbox

I'm trying to use VirtualBox sdk on Windows 7. 
To do this I'm using the sample code provided in VirtualBoxSDK\bindings\mscom\samples\ as a startup. This sample contains the following code:

```
 /* Instantiate the VirtualBox root object. */
    rc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VirtualBox,       /* the VirtualBox base object */
                          NULL,                   /* no aggregation */
                          CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,    /* the object lives in a server          process on this machine */
                          IID_IVirtualBox,        /* IID of the interface */
                          (void**)&virtualBox);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {
        printf("Error creating VirtualBox instance! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
        break;
    }
```

The code builds ok, links ok, but when I'm running it I get: Error creating VirtualBox instance! rc = 0x80040154(Could not load file or assembly error). 
I'm assuming that there is no server side(maybe) present that will provide the COM objects I'm trying to create with CoCreateInstance(). I'm only starting the sample provided but I'm assuming that there should be some server also running?!
The documentation provided does not mention anything about some server but this is what i think.
Thank you

Comment: Don't know, what's the reason for this issue. I just would like to tell you that I feel quite unhappy with VirtualBox's COM and SOAP APIs. They're glitching very hard. Consider using command line based VM control, because it's the one that was used the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be from the COM object. This sample is trying to get a server COM object. The solution was to install and start the Virtual Box application, this represents the server side. This server is, then, manipulated by this "client" provided.

Answer (score 0):

0x80040154 is "Class Not Registered".

1. try to register the component with regsvr32
2. if the component you are trying to instantiate is 64 bits, build
   a 64 bits project